# Fargate suddenly unable to start pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have a kubernetes cluster running in EKS. During a debuging session I've restarted coredns deployment and now Fargate is unable to bring up new pods

```
"reason": "MISCONFIGURED_FARGATE_PROFILE",
"message": "Misconfigured Fargate Profile: fargate profile kube-system blocked for new launches due to: Pod execution role is not found in auth config or does not have all required permissions for launching fargate pods."
```

This is quite surprising as `kube-system` Fargate profile remains unchanged, has `AWSFargatePODRole` role, which in turn has `AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy` amazon-managed policy attached to it, along with appropriate trust relationship.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "eks-fargate-pods.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Running `kubectl describe configmap aws-auth -n kube-system` also shows that

```
- groups:
    - system:bootstrappers
    - system:nodes
    - system:node-proxier\n
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::{ACC#REMOVED}:role/AWSFargatePODRole
  username: system:node:{{SessionName}}
```

I can't seem to find any information on what else could've gone wrong and would really appreciate any advice or hints on where to continue digging.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: were you able to find an solution for this? Currently facing this issue as well

Comment: @josescuderoh I ended up removing Fargate annotation instead. In my case it wasn't mandatory to use Fargate, so it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

One of the groups in your `aws-auth` ConfigMap has extra characters appended to the end of its name:

```
- system:node-proxier\n
```